# Android Studio passes wrong arguments to make in Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-studio

Android Studio is passing wrong arguments to make of NDK and this results in a compilation error. I'm trying to compile Cool Reader and it looks like Andorid Studio has messed up the path symbol ( \ and /). The original source was built on Linux and thereby the path is specified as /.

```
In file included from C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\cr3engine.cpp:18:0:
C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\/docview.h:7:23: fatal error: lvdocview.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\build\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cr3engine-3-1-0/C_\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\cr3engine.o] Error 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\ndk\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\build\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-17 NDK_OUT=C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\build\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\build\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    In file included from C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\cr3engine.cpp:18:0:
    C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\/docview.h:7:23: fatal error: lvdocview.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make.exe: *** [C:\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\build\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cr3engine-3-1-0/C_\Gowtham\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\projects\android1\app\src\main\jni\cr3engine.o] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Docview.h is called by `#include "docview.h"`

Comment: are your C++ sources are located outside the Android project directory ?

Comment: Check this if it can help http://www.egeek.me/2013/12/21/ndk-build-in-the-latest-gradle-android-plugin/

Comment: note that NDK complains about `lvdocview.h`, it did find `docview.h`.

Comment: @pyus13 yeah, some of the stuff is outside the jni directory, that link is helpful and directory referencing might be the problem. Checking.

Comment: Yep that's the problem it's lvdocview.h. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645743/referencing-relative-path-resources-from-android-ndk-manifest-file